# php pdo - retrieve results and row count - portable solution

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm currently querying the db twice to retrieve the row count of my result set, and my result set before I run loops on the rows returned like this:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable");
$result1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mytable");

$count = $result->fetchColumn();

if($count == $value){

while($row = $result1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
//execute code
    }
} elseif($count == $value2) { 
//execute other code 
}
```

I've just converted to PDO and so don't know it as well. The code used to use `mysql_num_rows`. I'm looking for a way I can do this without querying the db twice, this solution that I've been using works for small purposes but is obviously unnecessary load on the database if it were scaled. Many Thanks

EDIT: My reason for moving to PDO is for it's portability features, and thus `rowCount()` isn't suitable in every instance.

Comment: It always is a good idea to read the documentation of the tool you use. It shows you the list of available methods, for example. Here it shows you this: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: [`rowCount`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: @Script47 `rowCount` does not execute on `SELECT` statements.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy it works fine when I use it. *If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement.* Though it does come with the warning of: *However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.* However, it does work for me.

Comment: `rowCount()` does work for me in this instance using mysql, however given the warning in the documentation, and the reason for me converting to `PDO` was the fact that it's portable with most databases, it's not a long term fix.

Comment: @AdamCopley In case you don't want to use `rowCount()` method, I've provided an alternative method. See the **edited** section of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rowCount()` method to get number of rows, like this:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mytable");
$count = $result->rowCount();

echo $count;

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    // your code

}
```

Here's the reference:

- [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

**Edited:**

In case you don't want to use `rowCount()` method, this is another way of doing it.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mytable");
$result_set = $result->fetchAll();
$count = count($result_set);

echo $count;

while($row = array_shift($result_set)){

    // your code

}
```

Here are the relevant references:

- [fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)
- [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)
- [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Comment: apologies that was just a typing error, not a copy/pase of actual code, and doesn't answer the question I asked. Good observation nonetheless, I have edited now.

Comment: It should be noted that rowCount() is NOT guaranteed to work for SELECT queries across all platforms!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, there's no reason to perform a `COUNT(*)` query. You can just count how many rows were returned.

```
$count = $result->fetchAll();
```

Now `$count` holds reference to how many rows were returned.

Comment: This answer doesn't work whereas `$result->rowCount();` does.

Comment: @AdamCopley What about my solution doesn't work for you?

Comment: Vaguely yes, however you omitted the important `count($result)` which Rajdeep Paul provided and thus the first working solution to my problem. Thank you for your answer though, it is much appreciated.